# Process Monitor equivalent for Linux?

Tags: linux, debian, process, monitoring, software-rec

Is there a Unix/Linux equivalent of [Process Monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645), whether GUI or CUI?

If it makes a difference, I'm looking at Ubuntu, but if there's an equivalent for other systems (Mac, other Linux variants like Fedora, etc.) then knowing any of those would be useful too.

#### Edit:

Process *Monitor* is for monitoring system calls (such as file creation or writes), while Process *Explorer* is for monitoring process status (which is like System Monitor). I'm asking for the former, not the latter. :-)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The console standby for this is `top`, but there are alternatives like my favorite `htop` that give you a little more display flexibility and allow you a few more operations on the processes.

A less interactive view that is better for use in scripts would be the `ps` program and all it's relatives.

**Edit:** Based on your clarified question, you might note that `strace` handles watching system calls made by a given process including all read-write operations and os function calls. You can activate it on the command line before the program you want to track or attach to a running process by hitting <kbd>s</kbd> on a process selected in `htop`.

Comment: I believe `top` is the equivalent of Process *Explorer*, not Process *Monitor*, right?

Comment: How about you run it and explore the man page. I read through the feature list you linked to of process monitor and it sounded like `htop` covered all the details except boot sequence monitoring. At best it could be activated in `screen`/`tmux` sometime part way through a linux boot cylce.

Comment: In light of your other comments, you might also be looking for `strace`, which you can activate from `htop` by hitting `s` on a process or manually from the command line when you run something or with a process id.

Answer (score 16):

The grandaddy of all process monitors is [`top`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Top_%28Unix%29), and many system monitoring tools are called `top`. For example, there's [`iotop`](http://guichaz.free.fr/iotop/) to watch disk I/O, [`atop`](http://www.atoptool.nl/) for a bunch of system resources, [`powertop`](http://www.linuxpowertop.org/) for power consumption.

If you want more detailed information, it's not tracked by default. To watch what a **particular process** is doing, call [`strace`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strace) on it. For example, if you're only interested in filesystem accesses:

```
strace -s9999 -efile command_name    # trace a program during its whole execution
strace -s9999 -efile -p1234          # trace a running program with the given PID
```

`strace` is specific to Linux, but other systems have a similar tool: `truss` on Solaris, `ktrace` or `dtrace` under *BSD, etc.

To watch what's happening to a **particular file** or in a particular directory or directory tree, use the [inotify facility](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inotify).

```
inotifywait -m .
```

Again, the facility is specific to Linux, but most other unices have a similar system, e.g. [kqueue](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kqueue) under *BSD, and [FAM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_Alteration_Monitor) (originally from SGI but now available as an API on many systems).

To watch all the **system calls** under Linux, you can use the [audit subsystem](http://people.redhat.com/sgrubb/audit/). It's relatively recent and there's not much literature on the topic; search for `auditctl` or read the [`auditctl` man page](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/lucid/man8/auditctl.8.html). There are a couple of examples on this site: [tracking file accesses](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/12390/tracking-huge-buffer-usage-under-linux/12398#12398), [tracking process execution](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/13017/log-every-invocation-of-every-suid-program/13024#13024).

Comment: Are you sure you're referring to the equivalent of [Process Monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645), and *not* [Process Explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653)?

Comment: @Mehrdad: I see, I'd gone by the name and my memory of a tool I'd used on Windows (which is in fact Process Explorer), and not by the actual description. It's always dangerous to ask for the equivalent of a particular program, better to ask for a program with certain features.

Comment: Thank you. `iotop -o -b -P` shows me which processes are doing disk I/O operations

Answer (score 9):

You may want to take a look at `lsof` and `strace`.  Sysinternal's Process Monitor is actually Filemon and Regmon combined with a some additional enhancements. The `top` command is more like Process Explorer.

Answer (score 4):

I'm really late for answering this, but I have started a project that aims to do exactly what you're looking for. Have a look at it here: https://github.com/alexandernst/monks

Answer (score 4):

You are probably looking for [sysdig](http://www.sysdig.org/wiki/sysdig-examples/)

For example:

```
sysdig -A -c echo_fds
```

Answer (score 2):

I've not used that Process Monitor, but as far as I can tell it's the same as `gnome-system-monitor` on a Gnome system. If you use KDE they probably have something similar.

Comment: No, they're different. Process Monitor actually hooks system calls, not display process information. (What you're referring to is accomplished by Process Explorer, though.)

Comment: Oh, well I usually use the CLI tool vmstat for things like that. But that's system wide, not per process.

Answer (score 1):

dtrace4linux allows you to trace some interesting tidbits of the kernel. Although it appears to be more powerful than sysdig, unfortunately is not so well behaved.

Answer (score 0):

This was just released yesterday:

https://github.com/microsoft/ProcMon-for-Linux