# How to determine which process is creating a file?

Tags: process, files, monitoring

Given file path, how can I determine which process creates it (and/or reads/writes to it)?

Comment: I thought one of the inotify_tools (inotifywatch or inotifywait) would do this kind of thing.  These tools are great if you want to know when a filesystem event happens, but it doesn't look like you can get a pid from inotify.

Comment: You could do `inotifywait $file ; lsof -r1 $file`, though. It's much better than running `while` loops or using `watch`.

Comment: The problem is that by the time the `lsof` runs the file may already have been closed.

Answer (score 104, accepted):

The **[lsof](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lsof)** command (already mentioned in several answers) will tell you what process has a file open at the time you run it. `lsof` is available for just about every unix variant.

```
lsof /path/to/file
```

`lsof` won't tell you about file that were opened two microseconds ago and closed one microsecond ago. If you need to watch a particular file and react when it is accessed, you need different tools.

If you can plan a little in advance, you can put the file on a **[LoggedFS](http://loggedfs.sourceforge.net/)** filesystem. LoggedFS is a [FUSE](http://fuse.sourceforge.net/) stacked filesystem that logs all accesses to files in a hierarchy. The logging parameters are highly configurable. FUSE is available on [all major unices](http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/fuse/index.php?title=OperatingSystems). You'll want to log accesses to the directory where the file is created. Start with the provided sample configuration file and tweak it according to [this guide](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/13794/loggedfs-configuration-file-syntax/13797#13797).

```
loggedfs -l /path/to/log_file -c /path/to/config.xml /path/to/directory
tail -f /path/to/log_file
```

Many unices offer other monitoring facilities. Under Linux, you can use the relatively new  [audit subsystem](http://people.redhat.com/sgrubb/audit/). There isn't much literature about it (but more than about loggedfs); you can start with [this tutorial](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/linux-audit-files-to-see-who-made-changes-to-a-file.html) or [a](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5926947/getting-nfsstat-like-statistics-for-ext3-and-other-filesystems/5927229#5927229) [few](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/13017/log-every-invocation-of-every-suid-program/13024#13024) [examples](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/12390/tracking-huge-buffer-usage-under-linux/12398#12398) or just with the [`auditctl` man page](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/lucid/man8/auditctl.8.html). Here, it should be enough to make sure the daemon is started, then run `auditctl`:

```
auditctl -w /path/to/file
```

(I think older systems need `auditctl -a exit,always -w /path/to/file`) and watch the logs in `/var/log/audit/audit.log`.

Comment: From my understanding, LoggedFS and audit are like inotify in that they log the information. With something like vim's write feature, first foo.txt.swp is CREATED, then it is MOVED_TO foo.txt. This is logged (I use inotify), but the problem I now have is that when I am reviewing the logs, more often than not, I can no longer stat the foo.txt.swp file. This is creating a great deal of problems for me as the file may be deleted before the DELETE event is logged, so I try to get the file info and the OS complains the file no longer exists.

Comment: @puk This question was about logging, not about reacting to the operation. That would be a different question. OpenBSD's [systrace](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Systrace) is the leader here, though I think Linux has other things to offer.

Comment: I doubt I will find what I am looking for: callbacks for system operations

Comment: loggedFS, is pretty buggy, and it just dumps me sermentation core dumps after some time. And auditfs is enormously slowing my system..

Answer (score 14):

Well you could run `lsof` repeatedly, and if you're lucky the culprit will hold the file open long enough for it to show. Ie.:

```
$ lsof -r1 /path/to/file
```

or for many files

```
$ lsof -r1 /path/to/folder/*
```

This will list all access to the given path at a certain point in time, once per second. This includes listing the PID of the process accessing the file.

If that doesn't work, that is, the file is opened and closed very quickly, which is often the case, I believe you need to look for more elaborate tools. Maybe [loggedfs](http://loggedfs.sourceforge.net/) could be something?

**Hackland**
If the once-per-second `lsof` won't work, you could of course hack a while-loop that runs lsof repeatedly as fast as possible. Like:

```
$ while true; do lsof /paht/to/file; done;
```

Not pretty, but who knows, might just do it.

Comment: Suggesting running `while true` on a tool that doesn't give the right answer anyway isn't a great way to help a new unix user. There are better ways to trigger an action on a file create (see `inotifywait`) and better better ways to audit file system access (see [Gilles answer](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/13776/determine-which-process-is-creating-a-file/13791#13791)).

Comment: I tried your while suggestion on a file (bash on mac). Edited the file and saved it. `lsof` never showed anything.

Answer (score 1):

You can use **`lsof`** for that:

```
$ lsof /tmp/file
COMMAND    PID USER   FD   TYPE DEVICE SIZE/OFF    NODE NAME
less      4737 wena    4r   REG    8,6    90700 1643536 /tmp/file
```

It says the process named `less` is the keeping the file "**/tmp/file**" open.

**NOTE**: Strangely, that doesn't work if I use `geany` or `nano`. Am looking forward to better suggestions.

Comment: If the output (or lack of it) of `lsof` is to be believed and my understanding is correct, `less` opens a file but `emacs` does not. Strange.

Comment: I think that editors just open and read the file to the memory and close it. After that they only monitor file for changes (like vim).

Comment: The column that says `r` would be different if it were writing it.

Comment: @Random832: thanks for the correction.

Comment: Lukasz is correct; if you use `inotify -m /tmp/file` you can see that both `vim` and `nano` open, read/write to the file and close it immediately.

Comment: Vim opens a buffer in memory and writes to a file on save, emacs is similar i believe.

Answer (score 0):

```
lsof |grep (filename)
```

This will show you the process that is currently using the file.

Comment: There is no need for `grep` here. You can give `lsof` and argument of a specific filename to query and save a lot of time.

Comment: Ah cool to know. Honestly I only ever use it for finding open sockets so I don't really use it for actual files that much. Thanks for the heads up :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ls` and `grep` to find out the files used by chrome

```
$ ls -l /proc/*/fd | grep "chrome"
lrwx------ 1 ba abc 64 Jul 16 22:19 104 -> /home/abc/.config/google-chrome/Default/Cookies
lr-x------ 1 abc abc 64 Jul 16 22:19 113 -> /opt/google/chrome/nacl_irt_x86_64.nexe
lrwx------ 1 abc abc 64 Jul 16 22:19 121 -> /home/abc/.cache/google-chrome/Default/Cache/data_0
lrwx------ 1 abc abc 64 Jul 16 22:19 122 -> /home/abc/.cache/google-chrome/Default/Cache/data_1
lrwx------ 1 abc abc 64 Jul 16 22:19 123 -> /home/abc/.cache/google-chrome/Default/Cache/data_2
lr-x------ 1 abc abc 64 Jul 16 22:19 125 -> /home/abc/.config/google-chrome/Dictionaries/en-US-3-0.bdic
```

Another way is to use `lsof` and `grep`

```
$ lsof | grep "chrome"
chrome     2204       abc  cwd       DIR                8,5     4096 1441794 /home/abc
chrome     2204       abc  rtd       DIR                8,5     4096       2 /
chrome     2204       abc  txt       REG                8,5 87345336 5111885 /opt/google/chrome/chrome
chrome     2204       abc  mem       REG                8,5  4202496 1443927 /home/abc/.cache/google-chrome/Default/Media Cache/data_3
chrome     2204       abc  mem       REG                8,5  1056768 1443926 /home/abc/.cache/google-chrome/Default/Media Cache/data_2
chrome     2204       abc  mem       REG                8,5   270336 1443925 /home/abc/.cache/google-chrome/Default/Media Cache/data_1
chrome     2204       abc  mem       REG                8,5    45056 1443924 /home/abc/.cache/google-chrome/Default/Media Cache/data_0
```