# Is there a way to determine which process creates a file on osx 10.6.8

Tags: process, files, monitoring, trace

I would like to know which process has created files on os X 10.6. I'm trying DTrace, which probably will give the right answer, but I have not eyes to see the method.  I'm doing this because I think some oddities are happening with the Flash plugin, and triggering spotlight.

Comment: See also: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/13776/determine-which-process-is-creating-a-file

Comment: auditctl might be the way... looking into it thx

Answer (score 1):

Would `lsof` help? If the file is still open, you can see who has it open. Also very useful when you get "device or resource busy" errors.

Comment: No, lsof is not the way. See, I might come across a strange file, and wonder how it got there. DTrace is fine for the actual opening when it's open. But when I sit down and say "hmm where did this 'always_watchin_you.sol' file come from?", all i get is that it's my UID.