# Is there an easy way to check which program wrote to /var/log/messages?

Tags: centos

Is there an easy way to check which program wrote to which file? I'd like to check which program wrote an error to /var/log/messages for example.

Comment: It would be helpful if you showed some lines from your `/var/log/message` that appeared to lack a program name.

Comment: @John1024 can't I just check systemcalls that write to /var/log/message?

Comment: Possibly.  Is there a reason that you don't want to do it the easy way?

Comment: This question may help: [find which process is modifying a file](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/99074/find-which-process-is-modifying-a-file/99082). But, it is likely the case that the program writing to `/var/log/messages` is the syslog daemon, which just relays other programs' log messages.

Comment: @John1024 sshd is one of the programs that is writting to /var/log/message but after checking the PID, it turns out that that process is using the BASH command to write it. I don't know where the command file is.

Comment: @MarkPlotnick I can't find the reason why sshd is logging in /var/log/message

Comment: The reason: `sshd` calls syslog() to (potentially) log certain informational and error messages. It uses the `LogLevel` line in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` to decide which messages to send. Each message includes a _log level_ priority and a _facility_ name. `syslogd` receives these messages, looks at its own config file, and decides where to log the messages. `/var/log/messages` is the usual spot for the messages to go. What types of messages do you not want `sshd` to log?

Answer (score 9):

#### TL;DR

If you're only interestd in determining which process generated a given message in `/var/log/messages` then look at the first portion of each line. This shows the process name along with the PID of who generated a given line. In the examples below, `fprintd`, PID 444 and `gnome-session`, PID 8316 generated these lines in my `messages` log.

```
Feb 18 23:07:20 greeneggs fprintd[444]: ** Message: No devices in use, exit
Feb 18 23:08:53 greeneggs gnome-session[8316]: 23:08:53 | Git | personal_repo | Checking for remote changes...
Feb 18 23:08:53 greeneggs gnome-session[8316]: 23:08:53 | Cmd | personal_repo | git rev-parse HEAD
```

#### Analyzing writes

Processes don't write directly to `/var/log/messages`, rather they have to send their messages to `rsyslogd` which then managing writing messages to that log file. This is evident if you use the `lsof` command to see what files are opened in the `/var/log` directory by `rsyslogd`.

```
$ sudo lsof -p $(pgrep syslogd) | grep '/var/log'
lsof: WARNING: can't stat() fuse.gvfsd-fuse file system /run/user/1000/gvfs
      Output information may be incomplete.
rsyslogd 733 root    5w   REG              253,1 11413306    1323777 /var/log/messages
rsyslogd 733 root    6w   REG              253,1    61714    1318348 /var/log/cron
rsyslogd 733 root    7w   REG              253,1    60103    1323778 /var/log/secure
rsyslogd 733 root    8w   REG              253,1    49725    1323776 /var/log/maillog
```

#### Can we see with strace?

So one approach would be to see what processes write to `rsyslogd`, rather then the log file `messages` directly. To do this we're going to first have to determine the PIDs of all the `rsyslogd` threads.

```
$ sudo ps -eLf | grep rsyslogd
root       733     1   733  0    4 Feb17 ?        00:00:00 /sbin/rsyslogd -n
root       733     1   795  0    4 Feb17 ?        00:00:01 /sbin/rsyslogd -n
root       733     1   796  0    4 Feb17 ?        00:00:00 /sbin/rsyslogd -n
root       733     1   798  0    4 Feb17 ?        00:00:01 /sbin/rsyslogd -n
root     27863 23659 27863  0    1 22:14 pts/2    00:00:00 grep --color=auto rsyslogd
```

With the PIDs in hand you can use `strace` to watch as logs are written to `rsyslogd`. This is a bit of trial and error, but I was able to `strace` this PID and then use `logger` to simulate activity on my `/var/log/messages` log file.

#### Example

```
$ sudo strace -p 795 -s 2000 -o rsyslogd.log
```

Now I write a message using `logger`:

```
$ logger hey
```

If we watch our `strace` log file, `rsyslogd.log` we'll see this type of messaging as a result:

```
$ sudo tail -f rsyslogd.log
select(4, [3], NULL, NULL, NULL)        = 1 (in [3])
recvmsg(3, {msg_name(0)=NULL, msg_iov(1)=[{"<13>Feb 18 22:15:49 saml: hey", 8096}], msg_controllen=0, msg_flags=MSG_CTRUNC}, MSG_DONTWAIT) = 29
futex(0x7f41ba963d14, FUTEX_WAKE_OP_PRIVATE, 1, 1, 0x7f41ba963d10, {FUTEX_OP_SET, 0, FUTEX_OP_CMP_GT, 1}) = 1
futex(0x7f41ba963e70, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 1) = 1
select(4, [3], NULL, NULL, NULL
```

If we `strace` all the `rsyslogd` PIDs, logging all their output to different log files (`me*.log` where * = 1-4) and then `tail -f me*.log`, we now get an expanded view from our `logger hey` command:

```
==> me1.log <==
)        = 1 (in [3])
recvmsg(3, {msg_name(0)=NULL, msg_iov(1)=[{"<13>Feb 18 22:23:23 saml: hey", 8096}], msg_controllen=0, msg_flags=MSG_CTRUNC}, MSG_DONTWAIT) = 29
futex(0x7f41ba963d14, FUTEX_WAKE_OP_PRIVATE, 1, 1, 0x7f41ba963d10, {FUTEX_OP_SET, 0, FUTEX_OP_CMP_GT, 1}) = 1

==> me3.log <==
) = 0

==> me1.log <==
select(4, [3], NULL, NULL, NULL
==> me3.log <==
futex(0x7f41ba963e70, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 1) = 0
write(5, "Feb 18 22:23:23 greeneggs saml: hey\n", 36) = 36
futex(0x7f41ba963d14, FUTEX_WAIT_PRIVATE, 67373, NULL
```

We can see a bit more of what's going on, but we still can't make out exactly what process generated the message to `rsyslogd`.

#### How about using fatrace?

This is a newer addition to the tracing suite of tools but it can prove very useful in situations such as yours. You can trace all file I/O access system wide using this tool, but we can narrow its focus to just the `/var/log` directory to see if we can't find out what process is throwing log messages to `rsyslogd`.

#### Example

For starters we'd run this command to watch just `/var/log` messages.

```
$ sudo fatrace | grep /var/log
```

Now as processes start to access `/var/log` we'll get a steady stream of which process is doing the accessing.

Here's the output when I ran this command, `sudo -i`:

```
systemd-journal(340): O /var/log/journal/0ee868f8b7da40f48013a281826b1b84
systemd-journal(340): C /var/log/journal/0ee868f8b7da40f48013a281826b1b84
rsyslogd(733): W /var/log/secure
rsyslogd(733): W /var/log/secure
auditd(546): W /var/log/audit/audit.log
auditd(546): W /var/log/audit/audit.log
auditd(546): W /var/log/audit/audit.log
```

Here's root `ssh`'ing into the box via localhost, `ssh root@localhost`:

```
auditd(546): W /var/log/audit/audit.log
auditd(546): W /var/log/audit/audit.log
rsyslogd(733): W /var/log/messages
rsyslogd(733): W /var/log/messages
rsyslogd(733): W /var/log/secure
sshd(23718): O /var/log/lastlog
rsyslogd(733): W /var/log/secure
sshd(23718): RC /var/log/lastlog
sshd(23718): RCO /var/log/btmp
auditd(546): W /var/log/audit/audit.log
sshd(23724): RCO /var/log/lastlog
sshd(23724): O /var/log/wtmp
sshd(23724): W /var/log/wtmp
sshd(23724): W /var/log/wtmp
sshd(23724): CW /var/log/wtmp
sshd(23724): CW /var/log/wtmp
sshd(23724): CWO /var/log/lastlog
sshd(23724): CW /var/log/lastlog
```

So using `fatrace` could help you to start to pinpoint what process is ultimately driving log messages to `/var/log/messages`.

#### How do messages get to /var/log/messages?

If you take something like SSH the daemon, `sshd`, is configured by this config file, `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`. There is this line in that file which specifies where `sshd` should send its log file messages.

```
# Logging
# obsoletes QuietMode and FascistLogging
#SyslogFacility AUTH
SyslogFacility AUTHPRIV
#LogLevel INFO
```

So this means that `sshd` is making use of the `SyslogFacility`, and its only sending messages that are `AUTHPRIV` or higher. So then how do the messages make their way to `/var/log/messages`?

Take a look at `rsyslogd`'s config file, `/etc/rsyslog.conf`:

```
# Log anything (except mail) of level info or higher.
# Don't log private authentication messages!
*.info;mail.none;authpriv.none;cron.none                /var/log/messages
```

**NOTE:** Notice the `authpriv` on the left side there? That's what "routes" the messages from `sshd` to the file, `/var/log/messages`.

#### References

- [Determining Specific File Responsible for High I/O](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/86875/determining-specific-file-responsible-for-high-i-o/87290#87290)

Comment: I get something like 'sshd(23718): O /var/log/messages' But I still don't know why sshd writes to /var/log/messages. Where's this '/var/log/messages' defined?

Comment: Check your `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` file, there is this line: `SyslogFacility AUTHPRIV`, this tells `sshd` to send its logs to rsyslogd.

Comment: That line is commented out by putting a '#' in front of it, but it still sends logs to /var/log/message

Comment: @Jidrick - commenting it out just let's the default kick in, which that is. You need to change the level. Change LogLevel to QUIET and uncomment it.

Comment: Can you also remove this line '*.info;mail.none;authpriv.none;cron.none                /var/log/messages'?

Comment: @Jidrick - removing that disables all logging to that file.

Comment: @Jidrick - why don't you just look at the first part of each line in `/var/log/messages`? Example: "Feb 16 04:30:03 greeneggs NetworkManager[869]:.." shows which process generated a given message. So in this case, NetworkManager, PID 869, generated this message.

Comment: It says that sshd, PID 32330 generated the message. Changing LogLevel to QUIET did not stop sshd from logging to /var/log/messages

Comment: @Jidrick - Did you restart `sshd` after making the change?

Comment: @sln Yes, I did 'service sshd restart' but it still sends it to var/log/messages

Comment: What version of CentOS? Also please provide output of `ps -eaf|grep sshd`, as well as`rpm -qf /etc/ssh/sshd_config`.

Comment: Also please confirm the actual path. Is it `/var/log/message`? That's not the normal location, it's `/var/log/messages`.

Comment: @sln: CentOS 6.4 64 bit. Out of 'ps -eaf|grep sshd' shows things like: root 33450   1  0  4:13  ?  00:00:00 sshd: root@pts/1   and   root   808  1  0  04:26  ?  00:00:00  /usr/sbin/sshd. `rpm -qf /etc/ssh/sshd_config`. – slm 7 mins ago shows openssh-server-5.3p1-84.1.e16.x86_64. The path was indeed /var/log/messages

Comment: @Jidrick - OK, that looks good. So what msgs. are not showing up in `/var/log/secure`?

Comment: Is fatrace available for CentOS?  I just fired up a docker image to take a look and I don't see it in the standard yum repositories.