# How to locate an application that is using the 'bash' command?

Tags: centos

I saw a command called 'sshd' that is using the BASH command (according to `ps aux`) to write to a file. But how to locate the code of this application that is using the `bash` command?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there an easy way to check which program wrote to /var/log/messages?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/115822/is-there-an-easy-way-to-check-which-program-wrote-to-var-log-messages)

Comment: Is this machine in a cluster? Standalone or in an office? Are you the only user?

Answer (score 1):

The `sshd` is the daemon for [ssh](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secure_Shell). It is the receptive end of an (often) remote session. So the user or application communicating with the `sshd` will be driving `bash` command.

E.g. when I `ssh` into my server with `ssh root@server`, I get a `bash` prompt and when I then type `pstree -pa` I will get (excerpt):

```
  ├─sshd,789 -D
  │   ├─sshd,9306    
  │   │   └─bash,9488
  │   │       └─pstree,9547 -pa
```

So there might not be code that is using the bash command in a file on your system. I can however look in `/var/log/auth.log` (as @slm indicate on CentOS this info is normally `/var/log/secure`) and see:

```
Feb 19 05:37:38 owl sshd[9558]: Accepted publickey for root from 192.168.0.101 port 52628 ssh2
Feb 19 05:37:38 owl sshd[9558]: pam_unix(sshd:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
```

Which tells me the IP address of the machine where the `ssh` connection originated.

Comment: There is no `/var/log/auth.log` on RH distros, they use `/var/log/secure` and it typically contains slightly different things, but otherwise this A is correct.

Comment: @slm had not not noticed the centos until I read the other posts by OP