# Change sshd logging file location on CentOS?

Tags: centos, logs

How do I change the `sshd` logging file location on CentOS? `sshd` logs to `/var/log/messages` instead of `/var/log/secure`. How can I change the setting so `sshd` will stop sending logs to `/var/log/messages`?

Comment: You keep writing `/var/log/message` is that really the location? It's generally `/var/log/messages`.

Comment: @slm [here](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/115822/33055) it was `/var/log/messages`, maybe OP has both ;-)

Comment: On my ubuntu system, the ssh log is in `/var/log/auth.log`

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Please post your `sshd_config` something else would seem to be up. A stock CentOS system always logs to `/var/log/secure`.

#### Example

```
$ sudo tail -f /var/log/secure
Feb 18 23:23:34 greeneggs sshd[3545]: pam_succeed_if(sshd:auth): requirement "uid >= 1000" not met by user "root"
Feb 18 23:23:36 greeneggs sshd[3545]: Failed password for root from ::1 port 46401 ssh2
Feb 18 23:23:42 greeneggs unix_chkpwd[3555]: password check failed for user (root)
Feb 18 23:23:42 greeneggs sshd[3545]: pam_succeed_if(sshd:auth): requirement "uid >= 1000" not met by user "root"
Feb 18 23:23:43 greeneggs sshd[3545]: Failed password for root from ::1 port 46401 ssh2
Feb 18 23:23:48 greeneggs sshd[3545]: Accepted password for root from ::1 port 46401 ssh2
Feb 18 23:23:48 greeneggs sshd[3545]: pam_unix(sshd:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
Feb 18 23:24:05 greeneggs sshd[3545]: Received disconnect from ::1: 11: disconnected by user
Feb 18 23:24:05 greeneggs sshd[3545]: pam_unix(sshd:session): session closed for user root
Feb 18 23:27:15 greeneggs sudo:     saml : TTY=pts/3 ; PWD=/home/saml ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/bin/tail /var/log/secure
```

This is controlled through `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`:

```
# Logging
# obsoletes QuietMode and FascistLogging
#SyslogFacility AUTH
SyslogFacility AUTHPRIV
#LogLevel INFO
```

As well as the contents of `/etc/rsyslog.conf`:

```
# Log anything (except mail) of level info or higher.
# Don't log private authentication messages!
*.info;mail.none;authpriv.none;cron.none                /var/log/messages

# The authpriv file has restricted access.
authpriv.*                                              /var/log/secure
```

#### Your issue

In one of your comments you mentioned that your `rsyslogd` config file was named `/etc/rsyslog.config`. That isn't the correct name for this file, and is likely the reason your logging is screwed up. Change the name of this file to `/etc/rsyslog.conf` and then restart the logging service.

```
$ sudo service rsyslog restart
```

Comment: Thanks, I wondered, if "SyslogFacility AUTHPRIV" is commented out. How does sshd know what the defaults are? Are the defaults stored at some place you can edit?

Comment: The defaults are in the source code that was used to compile the `sshd` executable file. If you want to _override_ the defaults, you can give `sshd` command-line options or edit its config file.

Comment: @MarkPlotnick - yes as is typically done in configuration files (as seen above) the defaults are shown in the config file but are then commmented out. So `ssh` was compiled so that `LogLevel` was set to `INFO` by default. To overrride it you need to uncomment that line and then change its value.

Answer (score 3):

Default `sshd` syslog facility is `AUTH`, so it will be logged in syslog to `/var/log/messages`.

To make `sshd` log to new file, you can change it syslog facility to something others, then config syslog to log this new facility to new file, i.e:

In sshd_config, add this line:

```
SyslogFacility AUTHPRIV
```

Then in syslog.conf:

```
authpriv.* /var/log/secure
```

Comment: @Jidrick - something is very wrong with your box. It appears to be broken and missing things.

Comment: @Jidrick: you can check for other like rsyslog?

Comment: @Gnouc - `SyslogFacility AUTHPRIV` is already the default on RH distros. They override it as part of the packaging.

Comment: @Gnouc Yes, but changing this does not seem to work.

Comment: @Jidrick - change the name of the file `/etc/rsyslog.config` to `/etc/rsyslog.conf`.

Comment: @Gnouc How does sshd know what the defaults are? Are the defaults stored at some place you can edit?

Comment: @Jidrick: Just read `man sshd_config`