# Is it possible to get which process changed my file

Tags: files

I have many processes running on my Ubuntu. One day later, I find that one file has been changed. Now I want to know which process touched my file.

What can I do? (I can not modify the running processes)

Comment: maybe this link can help you. [https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/99074/find-which-process-is-modifying-a-file](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/99074/find-which-process-is-modifying-a-file)