# How to find which application is creating a particular file in a path?

Tags: files

The issue is that, one particular flat file is getting created in a directory.
I'm not sure which application is creating that flat file. 
I am using Unix environment.

Is there any possibility to identify which script/binary/application is creating that flat file.

Comment: What variant of Unix? What's the output of `uname -rs`?

Comment: I am using HP-UX B.11.11.

Answer (score 2):

as [Gilles](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/885/gilles) answer to this question: [How to determine which process is creating a file?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/13776/determine-which-process-is-creating-a-file)

```
lsof /path/to/file
```

after you locate the process you can determine the application using `ps`:

```
ps -ef | grep ProcessNumber
```

and to get only the Application use `awk`:

```
ps -ef | grep ProcessNumber | awk '{ print $8 }'
```

Comment: `lsof` will not help here if the file has been created and closed by the time `lsof` is called. On the other hand, `LoggedFS` may be more helpful as it can display process info when file is created.