# How to access temporary file straight after creation?

Tags: linux, command-line, files, tmp

I've script which is connecting to remote host via SSH, creates temporary file and executing the following command:

> Calling system(mysql --database=information_schema --host=localhost < /tmp/drush_1JAjtt)

Each time it's creating different file (pattern: `drush_xxxxxx`).

I've tried couple of times manually running on the remote:

```
tail -f /tmp/drush_*
```

but my connection is too slow and most of the time I've end up with the error:

> tail: cannot open `/tmp/drush_*' for reading: No such file or directory

Is there any trick accessing such file straight after it's being created to show it's content?

Comment: Related: [How to determine which process is creating a file?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/13776/determine-which-process-is-creating-a-file)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the file is created for enough short amount of time, you can run the following command on separate terminal before running the script:

```
while true; do cat /tmp/drush_* 2>/dev/null && break; done
```

Where `/tmp/drush_*` is your pattern. The advantage is that it's quick and you don't have to install any external tools (if you don't have e.g. admin/root permissions).

Please note that using `inotifywatch` (from `inotify-tools`) tool won't work in this particular case, because the file is created after the watches have been placed and the change will not be detected. Read more: [Why inotify doesn't print list of changed files?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/164794/why-inotify-doesnt-print-list-of-changed-files)

But still you can use `inotifywait` tool which efficiently waits for changes to files using Linux's inotify interface.

Here is the simple example:

```
inotifywait -m --format "%e %f" /tmp
```

And example to show the content of newly created files in `/tmp`:

```
inotifywait -m --format "%f" /tmp | grep --line-buffered ^drush | xargs -L1 -I% cat /tmp/% 2> /dev/null
```

Add `sudo` before `cat` if necessary. Change `/tmp` and `drush` to your suitable values.

Answer (score 5):

I've ran into this problem when [examining behavior of a particular application](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/468109/85039) I didn't trust. The application would create and later  delete its temp files.  [kenorb's solution](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/164802/85039) is good, however using `cat` can lead to race condition( that is a file may be removed while `cat` is working, so partial data only is retrieved).

A lower chance of race condition can be done with creating a hard-link to the file itself. `grep`ing and creating hard link can be combined via `awk`. Thus what I've came up with is the following;

```
inotifywait -e create -m --format "%w/%f" /tmp/suspicious_dir/ 2>&1 | 
awk 'NR>2{n=split($0,a,"/");system("ln "$0" /tmp/hardlink_to_"a[n]);}'
```

Since we're using `-e create` flag , we're only interested in temporary files that are going to be immediately created, and the output format gives us the full path to created temp file. Ignoring first two lines of output via `NR>2`. For every reported file, there will be created a hard link in form `/tmp/hardlink_to_<original filename>`

Comment: I love this idea! Especially since it preserves all data written to the file prior to deletion. (Unfortunately that means that if the program actually is malicious/dysfunctional and clears the contents of the file before deleting it, then you won't be able to retrieve the file contents very easily.

Comment: @NonnyMoose Very true. Well, this is the best I can come up with so far. Ideally, when you have access to the program you could either reverse engineer it, decompile, or run with debugger to see what actual data is being written, even `strace`. But for a non-security expert type of user this may be sufficient ( and for focus on attackers who assume file is gone after deleting original filename )

Answer (score 2):

You could set up a script that uses `inotify` (`inotify-tools` on `Debian`) and have it scan any changes of files in a particular directory. Then filter out the filename and `cat` it to a log file.

Answer (score 2):

drush is likely using that temp file in one of two ways:

1. It's creating the file; using it; and then leaving it around.
2. It's creating the file; using it; and then cleaning it up.

My guess is that you wouldn't be asking the question in case (1) because you could just inspect the file manually after the fact. So then the problem is that you want to inspect that temporary file during its momentary lifespan.

Using an external process to monitor for temp files may have a good probability of working -- though it depends on how long the temp files endure (5ms? 500ms? 5s? 5min?) and how quick your monitoring system responds.

Another approach is to instrument the "mysql" command to log the data you're interested in. For example, if "mysql" is in "/usr/bin/mysql", then you might create a file "/usr/local/bin/mysql" with:

```
#!/bin/bash
LOG=/tmp/mysql-commands
REALCMD=/usr/bin/mysql

NOW=$(date)
echo "[[$NOW: Running: $REALCMD $@]]" >> "$LOG"
tee -a "$LOG" | "$REALCMD" "$@"
exit $?
```