# Why doesn't inotifywatch detect changes on added files?

Tags: files, recursive, inotify

I'm trying to monitor my `/tmp` folder for changes using `inotifywatch`:

```
sudo inotifywatch -v -r /tmp
```

After creating couple of files (`touch /tmp/test-1  /tmp/test-2`), I'm terminating `inotifywatch` (by <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>C</kbd> which shows me the following statistics:

```
Establishing watches...
Setting up watch(es) on /tmp
OK, /tmp is now being watched.
Total of 39 watches.
Finished establishing watches, now collecting statistics.
total  attrib  close_write  open  create  filename
8      2       2            2     2       /tmp/
```

The output only prints the statistics, but not the files I expected (as in [here](https://serverfault.com/a/276795/130437) or [here](https://serverfault.com/a/269284/130437)). I tried different types of access (via `cat`, `mktemp`, etc.), but it's the same thing.

Did I miss something?
It's because I'm on VPS and something has been restricted?

OS: Debian 7.3 (inotify-tools) on VPS

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This is due to the way you're using `inotifywatch`, and the way the tool itself works. When you run `inotifywatch -r /tmp`, you start watching `/tmp` and all the files that are **already** in it. When you create a file inside `/tmp`, the directory metadata is updated to contain the new file's inode number, which means that the change happens on `/tmp`, not `/tmp/test-1`. Additionally, since `/tmp/test-1` wasn't there when `inotifywatch` started, there is no `inotify` watch placed on it. **It means that any event which occurs on a file created after the watches have been placed will not be detected**. You might understand it better if you see it yourself:

```
$ inotifywatch -rv /tmp &
Total of n watches.
$ cat /sys/kernel/debug/tracing/trace | grep inotifywatch | wc -l
n
```

If you have [enabled the tracing mechanism on `inotify_add_watch(2)`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/62284/41892), the last command will give you the number of watches set up by `inotifywatch`. This number should the same as the one given by `inotifywatch` itself. Now, create a file inside `/tmp` and check again:

```
$ inotifywatch -rv /tmp &
Total of n watches.
$ touch /tmp/test1.txt
$ cat /sys/kernel/debug/tracing/trace | grep inotifywatch | wc -l
n
```

The number won't have increased, which means the new file isn't watched. Note that the behaviour is different if you create a directory instead :

```
$ inotifywatch -rv /tmp &
Total of n watches.
$ mkdir /tmp/test1
$ cat /sys/kernel/debug/tracing/trace | grep inotifywatch | wc -l
n + 1
```

[This is due to the way the `-r` switch behaves](http://linux.die.net/man/1/inotifywatch):

> `-r`, `--recursive`: [...] If new directories are created within watched directories **they will automatically be watched.**

<sup>*Edit:* I got a little confused between your two examples, but [in the first case](https://serverfault.com/a/276795/181549), the watches are correctly placed because the user calls `inotifywatch` on `~/*` (which is expanded, [see don_crissti's comment here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/164794/why-doesnt-inotifywatch-detect-changes-on-added-files/164801#comment270577_164801)). The home directory is also watched because `~/.*` contains `~/.`. Theoretically, it should also contain `~/..`, which, combined with the `-r` switch, should result in watching the whole system.</sup>

However, it **is** possible to get the name of the file triggering a *create* event in a watched directory, yet I'm guessing `inotifywatch` does not retrieve this information (it is saved a little deeper than the directory name). `inotify-tools` provides another tool, called `inotifywait`, which can behave pretty much like `inotify-watch`, and provides more output options (including `%f`, which is what you're looking for here) :

```
inotifywait -m --format "%e %f" /tmp
```

From [the man page](http://linux.die.net/man/1/inotifywait):

> `--format <fmt>` Output in a user-specified format, using printf-like syntax. [...] The following conversions are supported:
>
> `%f`: **when an event occurs within a directory, this will be replaced with the name of the file which caused the event to occur**.
>
> `%e`: replaced with the Event(s) which occurred, comma-separated.

Besides, the `-m` option (monitor) will keep `inotifywait` running after the first event, which will reproduce a behaviour quite similar to `inotifywatch`'s.

Comment: `.bashrc` in the example @ `serverfault` does not appear in the stats because the user monitors its home directory recursively but because `path/.*` is expanded and as a result a watch is set for all the .files under `path/` (`.bashrc` included). The command used by the OP will never output file names because the watches are set for `/tmp` and any subdirectories therefore statistics will pertain only to `/tmp` and its subdirectories (i.e. you will see files have been accessed/moved/etc but it won't tell you their names).

Comment: @don_crissti Oops, I mixed up the two examples given by the OP. I edited my answer, thanks!

Comment: Thanks, it was useful. Here is my command to show content of all newly created test* files in `/tmp`: `inotifywait -m --format "%f" /tmp | grep --line-buffered ^test | xargs -L1 -I% sudo cat /tmp/% 2> /dev/null`.

Comment: Also: "_It means that any event which occurs on a file created after the watches have been placed will not be detected._" Any event (even the file creation) WILL be detected because a watch is ALREADY set for the containing directory and this is reflected in the statistics for that particular directory. See `inotifywatch` output in the OP question: the 2 `create` events are there (so they are detected) but since `inotifywatch` watches a directory (+any subdirectories) the statistics pertain only to that/those directories.

Comment: @don_crissti Even though an event is detected, it does not come from the file itself, but its parent directory: *"any event which occurs **on** a file"*.

Comment: I don't think we're on the same wavelength here... `man inotify`: `When a directory is monitored, inotify will return  events  for  the directory itself, and for files inside the directory.` Also, `man inotifywatch` is clear about which events are being watched:  > `EVENTS` > ... _A watched file **or a file within a watched directory** was accessed/closed/open/etc_ (means including events _"which occur on a file"_). Events for a file created after setting the watch on parent dir WILL be detected & reflected in `inotifywatch` stats (it will NOT mention for which files those events occured).

Comment: @don_crissti My bad, I didn't see that one. I must have been too focused on the `-r`ecursive aspect of the tools, and not enough on that particular behaviour of the API.