# What's overwriting my apt sources files?

Tags: debian, embedded

I'm working on a Phidgets SBC2. It's got emdebian grip, but grip has [is over](https://lists.debian.org/debian-embedded/2014/07/msg00003.html) and so I get 404 on those repositories when apt-get is trying to get package lists. I can get things to install using apt-get if I comment out the grip line in the /etc/apt/sources.list.d/multistrap-debian.list file. However, that file keeps getting re-created, as a comment in the file itself warns. Here is the contents:

```
#     DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE BY HAND -- YOUR CHANGES WILL BE OVERWRITTEN
deb http://www.emdebian.org/grip squeeze main dev java doc
deb http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian squeeze main contrib non-free
```

What is doing the overwriting, and how can I stop it?

(Edit: I assume multistrap is doing the overwriting, but I can't find the conf file that governs that. I have no /usr/share/multistrap directory. I think it's re-creating the file every time I do an apt-get update, maybe?)

Comment: When it recreates? Immediately after you delete it? After an specific event?

Comment: Take a look at `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d`, perhaps?

Answer (score 1):

If you can't figure it out from your system configuration or from online searches, use loggedfs or auditd to monitor accesses to the file. See [How to determine which process is creating a file?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/13776/how-to-determine-which-process-is-creating-a-file)

For example, with the [audit subsystem](http://people.redhat.com/sgrubb/audit/):

```
auditctl -a exit,always -w /etc/apt/sources.list.d/multistrap-debian.list
```

and watch the logs in `/var/log/audit/audit.log`. This will tell you the name of the process that changes the file. You may want to see what invokes it; you can do this by setting a watch on the executable, e.g.

```
auditctl -a exit,always -w /usr/lib/somewhere/strange/apt-source-list-editor
```

and you'll get an entry for the `execve` system call that executes the program.