# Something is creating thousands of .svg files in /tmp and not deleting them

Tags: filesystems, tmp

Apparently for months now, some process has been creating an empty .svg file in /tmp every minute and leaving it there. I now have 43,000 of these 262 byte files accumulated. I could just periodically delete them, but it'd be great if I could find the cause and even prevent it.

Does anyone know what this might be, or how to find out? I'd rather not try to figure out how to remount /tmp on a separate filesystem, like in [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/13791/109544), and auditctl hasn't worked for me. Short of these methods, am I left with running lsof in a loop? It hasn't yielded anything yet.

Here's the contents of the .svg (it's always the same):

```
$ cat /tmp/tmpuo80js2t.svg
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"                         standalone="no"?><svg id="empty" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"                         height="22" width="1" version="1.0"                         xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"></svg>
```

Update: The filename pattern is `/tmp/tmp????????.svg`. Some examples:

```
/tmp/tmpsxzk1ktl.svg
/tmp/tmpti2by97z.svg
/tmp/tmp0woym_0_.svg
```

Comment: First thing comes to mind is to check if there's a pattern in the date of creation of a file. Then try to use one of the tools you've tried earlier at the time next file is created.

Comment: is there a pattern to the file names?

Comment: Hopefully you're running your tasks under non-privileged accounts.  Does the owner of the files lend any clues to which process is creating them?

Comment: Can you upload the contents of `ps -aux` to pastebin?

Answer (score 1):

Okay, so it turns out I wasn't understanding auditctl correctly. I was able to use it to track down the culprit.

It turns out it was [indicator-sysmonitor](https://github.com/fossfreedom/indicator-sysmonitor). It [dies periodically](https://github.com/fossfreedom/indicator-sysmonitor/issues/84) on Ubuntu, so I'd wrapped it in a script which restarts it every minute. I assume it only creates this file on startup, and perhaps the way I kill it doesn't give it a chance to clean up. (I'll assume the error was on my part rather than it failing to clean up after itself.)

For posterity, here's how I tracked it down.

First, I started `auditd` watching `/tmp`:

```
$ sudo auditctl -w /tmp
```

Then, after it's been watching long enough to log the creation of one of the files, I picked the most recent one and searched the logs for it:

```
$ ls -lt /tmp/tmp*.svg | head -n 1
-rw------- 1 me me 262 Jul  5 13:42 /tmp/tmp4i0zh3mj.svg
$ ausearch -i -f /tmp/tmp4i0zh3mj.svg
```

The output contains a number of entries by several processes, but only one whose `nametype` is `CREATE`. The command (`proctitle`) of that one was `/usr/bin/python3 /usr/bin/indicator-sysmonitor`.